# Avoid image reload in [src] in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I have an app which shows a list of users with a profile picture.
When I update a value for this user the image gets reloaded as the observable list emits all data again.
How can I avoid this?

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
<img [src]="user.profilepic"/> {{user.name}} <button (click)="updateUser(user)">Update</button>
</div>
```

TS :

```
this.userProvider.getUserList()
      .distinct()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.users = data
      })
```

I hoped this distinct() function would do the job but no success..
The app is made with ionic 3 in combination with firebase realtime database data and firebase storage pictures downloaded with the public url

**EDIT**

3 years later I am facing the same issue in another app...
Everytime something comes in from my Observable, the images blinks (so I assume it refreshes?)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried checking to see if the value exists before you assign the value again?

Comment: Does it actually matter? The image should be pulling from cache if it has previously been displayed.

Comment: @Zze it does pull from cache in browser, but not in my cordova app. App is built with ionic but this doesn't matter for this problem I guess..

Comment: @Nicholas Can you please show how to do that? I am trying to keep a catalog as an Object with image urls but I guess the reload would still happen

Comment: Well you might try two approaches. You can check in the view by using an angular expression , or possibly just check in the subscribe function to see if the user data you need exists already before you attach it to `this`.

Comment: I would check it in the subscribe function but the problem is I do want to see other user data changes like user.name reflected in my app. This user.name gets updated by the button click and I see this change immediately.

Comment: @RobrechtVM did you find a fix for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. The issue still occurs in my app...

Comment: @RobrechtVM ok thanks!

Comment: try implement trackBy https://betterprogramming.pub/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878
it'll do a shallow compare and determine if a node need re-rendering

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `trackBy`.

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users; trackBy: trackBy">
    <img [src]="user.profilepic"/> {{user.name}} <button (click)="updateUser(user)">Update</button>
</div>
```

Then in your component define:

```js
public trackBy(index, user) {
    return user.id; // or any other identifier
}
```

This will prevent Angular of creating elements in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
<img [src]="user.profilepic"/> {{user.name}} <button (click)="updateUser(user)">Update</button>
```

I am assuming... after the successful update you are trying to fetch all user list again

```
updateUser(user){
//after the successful update
        this.userProvider.getUserList()
              .distinct()
              .subscribe(data => {
                this.users = data
             })
}
```

instead of fetching on the successful update ... you can update only one user (the updated user) in list

```
updateUser(user){
    //after the successful update

    this.userlist.find(a=> a.id== user.id).name = user.name;

    //can update whatever field you have uoadated
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You've to update individual user object as reassigning users array to refresh the html

```
this.userProvider.getUserList()
      .distinct()
      .subscribe(data => {
        if(!this.users) {
         this.users = data
        }
        else {
           for(let user of data) {
                 /* TODO find the user in this.users array & updated required properties, if user not found add it to this.users array*/ 
           }
        }
      })
```

Comment: I didn't try this solution because the way Vova Bilyachat solved it is really clean to implement. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: This wont help, i would even say it bad approach. Keep data immutable